Criando migrations com alembic
Estou enfrentando um problema ao tentar gerar migrations usando Alembic e SQLAlchemy. No meu projeto, estou organizando as models e a configuração do SQLAlchemy da seguinte forma:
Tenho uma pasta chamada model, onde cada entidade (model) é definida em um arquivo separado. Em uma pasta config, mantenho um arquivo chamado register.py, no qual inicializo uma instância de registry() e a armazeno em uma variável chamada table_register. Nas minhas models, utilizo o decorador @table_register.mapped_as_data_class para mapear as classes às tabelas no banco de dados. O problema ocorre quando executo o comando: .alembic revision --autogenerate
O arquivo de versão é criado, mas tanto a função upgrade quanto a downgrade aparecem vazias. Parece que o Alembic não está detectando as tabelas mapeadas no meu projeto.
Arquivo register.py:
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry

table_register = registry()

metadata = table_register.metadata

Exemplo de model:
from enum import Enum

from datetime import datetime

import sqlalchemy

from sqlalchemy import (String, func, ForeignKey)
from sqlalchemy.orm import (Mapped, mapped_column)

from configs.register import table_register

@table_register.mapped_as_dataclass
class Aluno():
    __tablename__ = 'aluno'
    
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, init=False, name='id_aluno')
    nome: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100), nullable=False, name='nome_aluno')
    serie: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('serie.id_serie'), nullable=False, name='serie_aluno')
    turma: Mapped[Enum] = mapped_column(sqlalchemy.Enum('A', 'B', name='turma_enum'), nullable=False, name='turma_aluno')
    created_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(name='created_at', server_default=func.now(), init=False)

configuração no alembic:
config = context.config
config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', Config().DB_URI)

target_metadata = table_register.metadata

def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section, {}),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, 
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            compare_type=True
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()

Apesar de aparentemente estar tudo configurado corretamente, o Alembic não detecta as tabelas e gera migrations vazias. Não sei se estou esquecendo algum detalhe na configuração do Alembic ou na forma como o registry() do SQLAlchemy é utilizado. O que pode estar causando esse problema? É necessário configurar algo adicional para que o Alembic reconheça tabelas definidas com registry.mapped_as_data_class?
